# Python 3 - Using beautifulSoup to find text in a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.rockefeller.edu/research/areas/summary.php?id=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
a = 'Comments'
for x in (soup.find_all('p')):
    if a in x:
        print (x)
    else:
        print ('it is not there')
```

Basically, I have a word in mind and I wish to know where it is in the page. Lets say my word is 'comment'. I want to know where that word comment is then : be able to print out the tag where it is included in (ex: `<a href=#>Comments</a>`

The updated code (that doesn't work for me)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = "http://www.rockefeller.edu/research/areas/summary.php?id=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for x in (soup.find_all(string=re.compile('comment', flags=re.I))):
    print(x.parent)
    print(x.parent.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify `string` keyword argument with compile regular expression object; it will return the string object include the text; You can access the tag that include the text using `parent` attribute:

```
import re

...

for x in soup.find_all(string=re.compile('comment', flags=re.I)):
    print(x.parent)
    print(x.parent.name)
```

Comment: I tried with your code but still didn't print anything, can you help me on this one?

Comment: did I missed something because when I run, it prints nothing.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = "http://www.rockefeller.edu/research/areas/summary.php?id=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for x in (soup.find_all(string=re.compile('comment', flags=re.I))):
    print(x.parent)
    print(x.parent.name)

Comment: @bob, It's hard to read the code in the comment because it does not preserve indentation and some word are interpreted as a markup.

Comment: @bob, Your code prints `<a href="/about/comments">Comments</a>` and `a` for me.

Comment: @bob, Which version of BeautifulSoup4 do you use? FYI, I'm using 4.4.0

Comment: same thing for me but still don't understand why it doesn't work!

Comment: here.. I posted another question with all the information if you wish to take a look :) link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757499/python-3-cant-print-using-the-re-library

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer and here it is:

```
for x in (soup.find_all(True,text=re.compile(r'comment', re.I))):
print(x)
```