# Python 3 - Can't print using the re library

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = "http://www.rockefeller.edu/research/areas/summary.php?id=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
for x in (soup.find_all(string=re.compile('comment'))):
    print(x.parent)
    print(x.parent.name)
```

It prints out nothing when I heard that it should print `<a href="/about/comments">Comments</a>` and `a`
I am using:
requests: 2.7.0
beautifulsoup4: 4.4.0
Python : 3.4.3
running on python Idle: Macbook Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.compile()` match case-sensitively by default. You got to set flag [`re.I`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.I) to make it case-insensitive. See the following demo example :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


url = "http://www.rockefeller.edu/research/areas/summary.php?id=1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for x in (soup.find_all(True,text=re.compile(r'comment', re.I))):
    print(x)
```

**output :**

```
<a href="/about/comments">Comments</a>
```

Comment: Yes it does work finally! Can you take a second to tell me what you changed and why?

Comment: @bob 1. `re.compile(r'comment', re.I)` : notice the 2nd argument for the reason explained in my answer. 2. `finda_all("a", ...)` : notice the 1st argument, it is so that the element `<a>` returned instead of just the text inside it.

Comment: it bothers me that you wrote to search for the text only in the <a> tag. Is there a way for me to use all possible tags instead of just <a>? imagine if the text (comment) was in a <p> tag for example. It could be in <a>,<p>,etc.

Comment: @bob `finda_all(True, ...)` instead to find all elements regardless of the element name